# how to find distance between hough lines in openCV?

Tags: opencv, python-3.6, distance, houghlinesp

I am new to `opencv-python`. I have found the lines in image through `houghtransformP`. The lines drawn from hough transform are discontinued and are giving multiple lines. I need to draw only one line for the edges and find the 'distance' between lines which are found.

The output image is shown below

```
"""
Created on Fri Nov  8 11:41:16 2019

@author: romanth.chowan
"""

import cv2
import numpy as np
import math


def getSlopeOfLine(line):
    xDis = line[0][2] - line[0][0]

    if (xDis == 0):
        return None

    return (line[0][3] - line[0][1]) / xDis

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inputFileName_ =r"C:\Users\romanth.chowan\Desktop\opencv\stent spec\2prox.jpeg"
    img = cv2.imread(inputFileName_)
    img1=cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(5,5),0)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edges = cv2.Laplacian(gray,cv2.CV_8UC1) # Laplacian Edge Detection
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 300, 10, 10)
    print(len(lines))
    parallelLines = []

    for a in lines:
        for b in lines:
            if a is not b:
                slopeA = getSlopeOfLine(b)
                slopeB = getSlopeOfLine(b)

                if slopeA is not None and slopeB is not None:
                    if 0 <= abs(slopeA - slopeB) <= 10:
                       parallelLines.append({'lineA': a, 'lineB': b})

    for pairs in parallelLines:
        lineA = pairs['lineA']
        lineB = pairs['lineB']

        leftx, boty, rightx, topy = lineA[0]
        cv2.line(img, (leftx, boty), (rightx, topy), (0, 0, 255), 2)


        left_x, bot_y, right_x, top_y = lineB[0]
        cv2.line(img, (left_x, bot_y), (right_x, top_y), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    cv2.imwrite('linesImg.jpg', img)
```

output image after drawing lines:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly [geometric task](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_(geometry)), not specific to OpenCV.

For each line you have two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) which are already used in your `getSlopeOfLine(line)` method.
You can denote each line in form:

**`ax + by + c = 0`**

To do that use two known line's points:

**`(y1 - y2)x + (x2 - x1)y + (x1y2 - x2y1) = 0`**

Note than parallel lines have same **`a`** and **`b`** while different **`c`**.

And than measure distance between any two of them (distance between non-parallel lines is equal to zero since they have a crossing point) :

**`d = abs(c2 - c1) / sqrt(a*a + b*b)`**

In Euclidean geometry line may be denoted in several ways and one may suit specific task better than another.

Currently you evaluate line's slope, from formula above we can get:

**`y = (-b / a)x - c / b`**

same to (b has another meaning now)

**`y = kx + b`**

Or using two line's points:

**`y = (x1 - x2) / (y1 - y2) * x + (x1y2 - x2y1)`**

Where **`k`** is line's slope (**`tan(alpha)`**) and **`b`** is shift.
Now you just match parallel lines (one with close **`k`**). You can take in account line's shift to merge several parallel lines into one.